# Web Application Stress/Load Test using a simple Web Service

Tags: java, testing, web-applications, jmeter

I am currently writing a JMeter plugin to test the fix for a bug that only seems to occur when our web application is under heavy load.

As a general solution to allow load/stress tests to be written to test specific sections of the web application I am think of adding a simple restful web service to call the tests.  The main reason to do this is to bypass the browser as what we are interested in testing for this is the business logic and database access layer (legacy inline SQL).

Would this be worth the time and effort or is it possible to use JMeter to test a complex web application that requires authentication and uses Javascript and Ajax heavily.

**EDIT**

The goal of these tests is to test how the business logic and data access layer handle heavy load situations to ensure there are no bugs or concurrency issues.  This is a legacy jsp web application (i.e. written in the early-mid 90s) with mostly inline sql that is in the process of being moved to a DAL layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get several benefits from a exposing a special API just for load tests:

- This API will be stable, the web UI tends to change (inputs, buttons, etc)
- You could design your API so it's possible to create relevant loading scenarios that are hard to simulate through the web UI
- Creating the loading scenarios will be much easier, whether using JMeter or a similar tool, or just a script using curl

Now all that's left is estimating how much work creating such an API will take, and whether the benefits are worth it.

Comment: The reason why I'm not too fond if creating a special API only for testing is because of the need to ensure that the special API is removed in the build process when creating a release version, or secured so as not to create a backdoor.  However, if secured this could be an added feature making integration with third-party systems easier.

Comment: Yeah benefits like those are why I was considering it and hopefully I can keep it to a simple config flag and servlet so it's not too much work.

Comment: @beny23 the only security risk would be from DOS attacks it wouldn't be exposing any data, also you can use a static constant as a c style preprocessor flag if you want to make sure that it doesn't go into a release version.

Comment: @eaglestorm I've been bitten before where due to a mix-up I called service in production instead of the test environment, so my advice would be to make sure that the test method isn't easily called in a non-test environment to avoid unintentional cockups, for Sod's law states that it'll only ever happen just when the production load peaks :-)

Answer (score 1):

The trouble with going straight to the business logic is that you can never be sure that you haven't got a problem in the presentation layer that is putting extra load on your server. And testing the business logic on its own could mean missing possible performance problems (e.g. if there are a lot of objects in a lot of HTTP sessions, your server could be spending most of its time in the garbage collector, because the heap is too low), so I would recommend creating a complex test plan that encompasses all calls to the server.

The easiest way to achieve this is using JMeter's HTTP Proxy, fire up your browser, and let the HTTP proxy record the test plan for you.

See [Basic JMeter Proxy Step By Step](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) on how to get started with the proxy.

This will record all the calls made from the browser to the server (you're not interested in the javascript itself, as this happens on the browser, so won't affect the server load, though the AJAX calls will).

The Test Plan created by the HTTP proxy will hardcode all the values, so you'll probably have to go through it to identify which values are different on each call (e.g. if you have a create option that returns a new ID, subsequent requests need to use the ID returned by the server.

To obtain these values you can add [Regular Expression Extractors](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) to your requests and assign a variable name which can then be reused as a request parameter in a subsequent request.  Going through the request parameters and identifying which need to be replaced by values which need to be parsed from previous pages can be a bit tedious, but is not that hard.

For example if you're page contains a recordId in the return HTML

```
<input type="hidden" name="recordId" value="abcqwer123" />
```

which needs to be used in the next request, you can use the following regex to extract it:

```
name="recordId"\s+value="([a-z0-9]+)"
```

Another thing to bear in mind is to ensure that you are using a wide range of test data (e.g. if you simulate a number of user logins, you'll want to ensure that not every test runs with the same userId, as caching may mean that heavy operations such as DB lookups are only done on your first run.  In order to simplify using multiple accounts, you can use the [CSV Data Set Config](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to load a list of values into a variable which then changes with every iteration.

My last advice is to look into running JMeter in [Distributed Mode](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/remote-test.html).  This is where you start Jmeter-server on a number of remote clients that then all execute the same test.  This ensures that the test clients themselves create bottlenecks by not having enough CPU cores or network bandwidth to create a large number of simultaneous requests.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not really interested in performance tests as such but testing concurrency and bugs that happen in the DAL while the system is under load.  But if we needed to optimize performance this would be worth considering and we will probably do this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing a REST service and invoking that through JMeter, if you have JUnit tests, you could use the [JUnit Sampler](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request) and reuse existing tests of the Data Access and Business Layers.